# Animating arrows using CSS3 to provide a cyclic movement effect

Tags: css, css-animations

I have tried to make an animated arrow like like the one in this [site](https://www.google.com/drive). A demo of my code attempt is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nqnuu3ck/). But the animation is not working in-line with the animation in the site.

My Code :

```
.animated-arrow-1 {
    -webkit-animation: arrow1 3s infinite ease-out;
    animation: arrow1 3s infinite ease-out;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0
}

 .animated-arrow-2 {
    -webkit-animation: arrow2 3s infinite ease-in;
    animation: arrow2 3s infinite ease-in;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1
}


@-webkit-keyframes arrow1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }

    90% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,36px);
        transform: translate(0,36px)
    }
}

@keyframes arrow1 {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }

    90% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,36px);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,36px);
        transform: translate(0,36px)
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes arrow2 {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }

    90% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,36px);
        transform: translate(0,36px)
    }
}

@keyframes arrow2 {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }

    90% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
        transform: translate(0,0)
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0,36px);
        -ms-transform: translate(0,36px);
        transform: translate(0,36px)
    }
}
```

Could you please anybody tell me what I missed here?

Comment: sorry i update the site link , in google drive mean page u can see in the bottom the arrow icon with the needed animation.

Comment: You need it to be like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nqnuu3ck/1/)?

Comment: yes you close  thank u

Comment: sure , accepted gladly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were reasonably close to achieving the required animation. In your code, there was only one movement from 0px to 36px for both the arrows but what was actually needed is a two stage animation with different keyframe settings for the two arrows. One arrow should start invisible at 0px, fade-in to 50px, stay there and then fade-out to 100px whereas the other arrow should start visible at 50px, fade-out to 100px, immediately go to 0px and then fade-in at 50px.

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
}
.icon img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
.animated-arrow-1 {
  animation: arrow1 3s infinite linear;
  opacity: 0
}
.animated-arrow-2 {
  animation: arrow2 3s infinite linear;
  opacity: 1;
}
@keyframes arrow1 {
  0%, 10% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  50%,
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 50px)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 100px)
  }
}
@keyframes arrow2 {
  0%, 10% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 50px);
  }
  50%,
  60% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 100px)
  }
  61% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 50px)
  }
}
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon">
  <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/ibsmfp6w9/Down_Arrow.png" class="animated-arrow-1" />
  <img src="http://s12.postimg.org/ibsmfp6w9/Down_Arrow.png" class="animated-arrow-2" />
</div>
```